# How to remove unwanted break in bootstrap panel

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, panel

I have panel where I'm displaying some basic informations about user. I want to display graph in the center of this panel.

I have problems with one unwanted space which I want to remove but I don't know how to do it.

Please look at image: [image: Problem]

Code for this panel:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Detail zákazníka <a href="<?php echo site_url('zakaznici/'); ?>" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left pull-right"></a></div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>ID zákazníka:</label>
    <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['ID_zakaznici'])?$zakaznici['ID_zakaznici']:''; ?></p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Meno:</label>
    <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['meno'])?$zakaznici['meno']:''; ?></p>
   </div>

   <div class="panel-body" align="center">Graph will be displayed here</div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Priezvisko:</label>
    <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['priezvisko'])?$zakaznici['priezvisko']:''; ?></p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email:</label>
    <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['email'])?$zakaznici['email']:''; ?></p>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Adresa:</label>
    <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['adresa'])?$zakaznici['adresa']:''; ?></p>
   </div>


   <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo site_url('Zakaznici/viewusersvypozicky/'.$zakaznici['ID_zakaznici']); ?>" role="button">Zobraziť prenájmy</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing the form tag. See this also: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Answer (score 1):

`p` tags create line breaks. You could replace the `p`  tag with a `span` tag to remove the unwanted break.

Your `div` with the class name 'panel-body' is also occupying space. You could add `position: absolute;` to its defined styles and it would not create that break.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Detail zákazníka <a href="<?php echo site_url('zakaznici/'); ?>" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left pull-right"></a></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>ID zákazníka:</label>
        <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['ID_zakaznici'])?$zakaznici['ID_zakaznici']:''; ?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Meno:</label>
        <span><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['meno'])?$zakaznici['meno']:''; ?></span>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body" align="center">Graph will be displayed here</div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Priezvisko:</label>
        <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['priezvisko'])?$zakaznici['priezvisko']:''; ?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email:</label>
        <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['email'])?$zakaznici['email']:''; ?></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Adresa:</label>
        <p><?php echo !empty($zakaznici['adresa'])?$zakaznici['adresa']:''; ?></p>
      </div>


      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo site_url('Zakaznici/viewusersvypozicky/'.$zakaznici['ID_zakaznici']); ?>" role="button">Zobraziť prenájmy</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "panel panel-default col-4">
        <div class = "panel-body">

        //your matter

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "panel panel-default col-4">
        <div class = "panel-body">

            //your graph

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed the p's are block level elements and create linebreaks - but Bootstrap also stlyes them with a 10px margin bottom so you may want to overwrite that with

```
p { margin-bottom: 0;}
```

I do not recommend this - the ideaa of the margin bottom is to separate text elements.

What will be causing your space issue where you have indicated is that you are using a div with a  .panel body class within the panel body.

```
<div class="panel-body" align="center">Graph will be displayed here</div>
```

**Bootstrap styles the panel body with 15px padding** - so either 
a) replace that class with a different class (this is what I would do - it makes no sense to have a .panel-body -within a .panel-body)

b) remove the padding from the nested panel body

```
.panel-body > .panel-body { padding: 0}
```

But as I said - a panel body within another one is semantically wrong.